# I can't use NetBeans IDE 8 for Fortran code

Tags: windows, netbeans, fortran

I want to use NetBeans IDE 8 to compile my Fortran code.
I have installed NetBeans and MinGW.
The following addresses are added to Environmental Variables:

```
"C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin"
```

After running a simple code like this

```
"   subroutine bar()
    print *, 'hello from bar...'
    end
"
```

I receive the following long message:

```
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Behi/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Hello_3'
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/hello_3.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Behi/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Hello_3'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
make.exe[2]: mkdir: Command not found
make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/bar.o] Error 127
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Behi/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Hello_3'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Behi/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Hello_3'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)
```

Can any one give me some suggestions?

Comment: `make.exe[2]: mkdir: Command not found` -- have you checked mkdir; is it installed and working?

Comment: Added to "Environmental Variables"?  What exactly did you do?